# Find the radius of the circle under these given conditions.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

I tried to solve the question by considering the circle to be an incircle of 2 triangles joined as in this manner :

[image]

Now, this is my solution :

Let AE =X then AF =x ( properties of tangent )
This means , EB = 5 -x
Implies BC =5-x
By doing this to the lower triangle, we get CD also as 5-x

BC+CD = BD = 6
Then , we find X. How do we calculate r after this? Have I gone wrong in my method ?

Comment: Why $EB=5-x$ should be true ?

Comment: $X$ is not the radius of the circle.

Comment: You drew $B$ and $C$ the wrong way round.

Comment: Yeah will edit that right away. What I meant is that after finding X I don't know how to calculate r

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition was right. Here is the formula and the correct solution:

$r=\frac{Area}{half-perimeter}=\frac{6\times 4:2}{(5+5+6):2}=\frac{12}{8}=\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

Join the center of the circle $O$ to $E$. Then $$AO= AC-OC = 4-r$$ and $$OE=r,$$ so $$\sin \angle BAC = \frac 35 = \frac{OE}{AO} =\frac{r}{4-r} \implies r=\frac 32. $$ Note here I am considering the diagram you drew to refer to points.

Comment: Beat me to it... Also OP should note that this answer uses the fact that $\angle OEA$ is a right-angle because the line $AC$ is tangent to the circle and line $OE$ is the radius.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Right :)